# Alamofire 5 multipart image upload issue swift for flask API

Tags: python, swift, flask, multipartform-data, alamofire5

I was trying to upload single image via Alamofire 5 multipart data, API is working fine on Postman as well as on android side, but it is not working on iOS side.
API is developed in Python flask. Image is taken from camera and by using JPEGCompression uploading image.

Following is my code:

```
func postMultipartData(imageData: Data, completion:@escaping (Result<AccuracyModel?, ErrorResponse>) -> Void) {
        let url = APIConstant.ImageAccuracyBaseUrl.BASEURL
        let mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
               "Content-Type": ContentType.multipart.rawValue
        ]
        
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file123.jpg", mimeType: mimeType)
            print(multipartFormData.boundary)
        }, to: url, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
           method: .post,
           headers: headers).response { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 || response.response?.statusCode == 201 {
                    do {
                        
                        if let data = response.data {
                            
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                            print(json ?? "")
                            
                            let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(AccuracyModel.self, from: data)
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                completion(.success(decodedData))
                            }
                        } else {
                            print(response)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        completion(Result.failure(self.generateErroModel()!))
                    }
                } else if response.response?.statusCode == 500 {
                    completion(Result.failure(self.generateErroModel()!))
                } else {
                    fallthrough
                }
                
                break
            case .failure(_):
                completion(Result.failure(self.generateErroModel()!))
            }
        }
    }
```

For testing purpose api is using 5000 port, can that be issue?
There are no parameters required, so not sending any.

I have also tried by using NSURLSession, but no luck.

For Flask code, I have referred following link:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/flask_rest_api_tutorial.html

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get any response ?

Comment: yes, getting response as: failure(Alamofire.AFError.sessionTaskFailed(error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x28028c510 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1A125234-A3F4-4BAF-B687-E81516363016>.<9>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <1A125234-A3F4-4BAF-B687-E81516363016>.<9>"